# REST API without Connected App

Tags: rest-api, external-app

I have to design an external app which will retrieve information from Salesforce. Any user can install this app and use it. This app will use rest API to access information from Salesforce. I cannot force the users belonging to multiple orgs to create a connected app in their instance to generate consumer key and consumer secret. Ideally users must be able to enter username and password+security token to access the data. Is there a way to achieve this or any other way without much customization by the admin.

Comment: Saranya, can you add any details/specifics about how you resolved this per your comment, you were "able to implement the functionality via Username - password flow" Was this in PHP or something else? Thanks

Comment: @Xtremefaith I tried this functioanlity in apex itself. I was able to access another developer org from my developer org using username-password flow.

Answer (score 25, accepted):

Definitely doable. The admin should not have to customize anything:

1. create your Connected App, **once**, in an org with a managed package and namespace,
2. bake that exact `client_id` into the runtime code that you distribute,
3. use Web Server authentication flow or Username-Password flow when calling REST API,

Maybe there is a misunderstanding of how `Connected App` really operates here. Imagine a Salesforce Package as an analogy. You control the true source code in a Packaging / Release Org but you deploy or install a special *instance* of it. Similarly with a Connected App:

- you control the Connected App 'definition' including `client_id` and `secret`,
- a user *allows* (or a sysadmin can *manage*) the connected app 'instance' when it's used.

Does this help?

Comment: solid answer, this is a regular misconception of OAuth clients

Comment: The app is not a Salesforce app. This will be a mobile app which can be installed by anyone. This means that multiple org users will use it. Do you still mean that this app can just hard code client_id and secret from some sample org and access other orgs without creating the connected app in each and every org?

Comment: Yep @Saranya you got it! The `client_id` and `secret` will be the same for everyone who uses the app. But don't use just any 'sample org', make a special org with a namespace and hold onto it.

Comment: One catch is that you will need a separate Connected App to support sandboxes. Or at least my experience is that I needed one to use for sandboxes and one for production/dev orgs. They same may also be true for pre-release orgs.

Comment: Don't distribute an app containing a secret. If you do, it's not really a secret any more. As Daniel says, use the user-agent flow.

Comment: Ah good spot @metadaddy - `secret` is optional_ for that flow right?

Comment: You just don't use the secret with user-agent flow - see https://developer.salesforce.com/page/Digging_Deeper_into_OAuth_2.0_on_Force.com#Obtaining_an_Access_Token_in_a_Browser_or_Native_Application_.28User-Agent_Flow.29

Comment: Thanks for the replies. I was able to implement the functionality via Username - password flow and I created the connected app only once. Shall I go with the Username password flow itself or switch over to User agent flow. kindly advise.

Comment: Strongly recommend trying to use User Agent flow if you can @Saranya. It doesn't need the `secret` and absolves one of a lot of responsibility.

Comment: Would it be a security issue at all to create this connected app in our production Salesforce instance instead of a standalone developer account?

Comment: @JonathanMcIntire no. If it's for internal use, the connected app in your production instance makes sense as you say. If it's an app you plan to distribute, put the connected app in your packaging / release org with the namespace.

Comment: @bigassforce May I know, how workbench type applications work with salesforce. Like, I dont create connected app, but the workbench itself creates that in my org. How can I do that? any hint/links/references? Thanks.

Comment: @YsrShk Note, when you click "Allow" for Workbench, salesforce deploys an Installed Package using their internal automated process user. To do the same, you could invoke the Metadata API from your app.

Comment: @bigassforce I have a requirement where I need a different callback URL for the connected app in each subscriber org. I tried to create the app using the URL method, still there is a limitation that I need to have the same callback URL. otherwise, I get `error=redirect_uri_mismatch&error_description=redirect_uri%20must%20match%20configuration` while authenticating.

Answer (score 2):

[@mattandneil's answer](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/a/56344/102) is correct in that you don't need separate connected apps for each org.

As per metadaddy's comments, for an external app the [OAuth 2.0 User-Agent Flow](https://help.salesforce.com/apex/HTViewHelpDoc?id=remoteaccess_oauth_user_agent_flow.htm&language=en_US) is more secure with Salesforce handling the username and password input and the `secret` not being embedded in the application that is distributed to the client.

From the docs (my emphasis):

> [For applications] implemented in a browser using a scripting language such as JavaScript, or from a mobile device or a desktop application. **These consumers cannot keep the client secret confidential.** The authentication of the consumer is based on the user-agent's same-origin policy.
>
> ...
>
> This user-agent authentication flow doesn't utilize the client secret since the client executables reside on the end-user's computer or device, **which makes the client secret accessible and exploitable**.

---

Generally speaking, don't do the following unless someone has a gun to your head. It's much better all round for everyone if the user never directly gives you their credentials.

That said, there are alternatives available, such as the [OAuth 2.0 Username-Password Flow](https://help.salesforce.com/HTViewHelpDoc?id=remoteaccess_oauth_username_password_flow.htm&language=en_US). Once you have collected the username and password+securitytoken you can use the password grant_type to get an access token.

Also note that the access token is generally interchangeable with a session id (depending on the [scope](https://help.salesforce.com/apex/HTViewHelpDoc?id=remoteaccess_oauth_scopes.htm&language=en_US) requested). You could also get the session id from the SOAP API login methods, composite apps, or even from a browsers Salesforce sid cookie.

Comment: Please don't collect the password from the user and use username/password flow! :-o

Comment: @metadaddy I've added some clarification and stronger wording about usage.  It is still an option, even if it is less than ideal. :-)

Comment: Cool. Handling user credentials unnecessarily is just not a good idea :-)