# How to generalize Integration components in Managed Packages

Tags: managed-package, oauth2, connected-apps, apexrest, apex-webservice

I am creating a managed package with a connected App to integrate with an external system( oAuth configured). The external system uses my developer organization's Consumer key and secret right now to push data from its end.

While installing this in a new SF Org should i again create a connected App and generate a new Consumer Key and Secret ?  If yes, is there a way to make it package-specific rather than org-specific ? (or) Is there a way to automate the process of generating the consumer key and secret ?

Thanks in Advance !

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the same consumer key and secret for different orgs. Refer this link- [REST API without Connected App](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/56342/rest-api-without-connected-app/56344#56344)