# How to authenticate without the need of a consumer key

Tags: authentication

Basically, I'm trying to figure out a way to authorize an application to use the Tooling API, but I would like to not have to set up a Connected Application. I've seen [this](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/63482/how-to-connect-to-salesforce-rest-api-without-oauth-how-does-jitterbit-do-it) question, but it doesn't really help me understand how to do it.

I've read about the Web-Server auth flow and the User-Agent flow, but both need a Consumer Key, according to the docs. What am I missing? If the only way to do this, like the previously cited answer states, is to use a SOAP login call and then with the key, do the REST calls, why is that?

Answer (score 0):

There are several possible ways to authenticate your Client App making API calls to Salesforce: OAuth 2.0, SessionId and SOAP SessionID. That's it.

(1) [Understanding Authentication](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.api_rest.meta/api_rest/intro_understanding_authentication.htm) with OAuth:

> Salesforce **uses the OAuth protocol** to allow users of applications to
>   securely access data without having to reveal username and password
>   credentials.

(2) As @sfdcfox states in his [answer](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/a/63487/36878), SessionId is basically used for testing purposes. And this is fair because SessionId is valid as long as user's session is live.

(3) As a third option you can use the [login()](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.api.meta/api/sforce_api_calls_login.htm) SOAP call that in case of success will return [LoginResult](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.api.meta/api/sforce_api_calls_login_loginresult.htm) with **sessionId** which you then use in API REST calls, like [here](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.api_rest.meta/api_rest/intro_curl.htm).

Although with option 3 you don't need to set up a connected app, you will have to deal with 2 APIs SOAP and RESP, which might not be very convenient.

Comment: I have a couple of questions based on your answer: why is the SessionId only used for testing purposes, and why can't I obtain it via the REST API? And thirdly, what's the difference between a SessionId and an AccessToken emitted by the REST API?