# Connected App issue with Rest API

Tags: rest-api, connected-apps

I was trying to connect one Salesforce Org to another via Rest API.

From the knowledge I've, I was thinking I've to create 'Connected APP' in the target(receiving org)where I've to update some data using data from Sending Org.

Mistakenly, i created 'Connected APP in 'Sending Org' and use its Client ID and Secret to send data. 
This was working fine and later I got surprised to find that I've created Connected APP in  Sending org!

I later Created the connected APP in Receiving org also and found that using its Client ID and Secret also, it is working fine!

This all led to lots of confusion 
I read further and found this article :

[REST API without Connected App](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/56342/rest-api-without-connected-app)

From which I understood, Connected Apps could be created in Sending APP also. 
it seems to depends upon types of flows, like 
1. User Agent flows 
2. Web authentication flow

I was reading [this](https://help.salesforce.com/HTViewHelpDoc?id=remoteaccess_oauth_web_server_flow.htm) article to get clarification : 
But I got further Confused

Could some body please help in shedding light : 
1) why my Rest API call was working fine, even if Connected APP setup was done in Sending org?
2) in simple language , difference between these Oauth flows?  I know it has to do something based on if you app is residing on webserver or on Client device like(Mobile etc). But what is native difference in terms of way they are functioning?

Thanks!